# Convert AdSense earnings into AdWords

Tags: google-adsense, google-ads

Does anybody know how to convert AdSense earnings into AdWords?

By placing AdSense banners on a website, the webmaster collects some "potential" through the means of money + taxes + other routine work.

I'm wondering if the AdSense earnings can be somehow converted into AdWords "potential" and be spent again for the website.

Theoretically, it's just Ad Exchange, but the beauty of AdSense and AdWords is that both platforms have pretty solid client databases.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty simple: you just collect your AdSense earnings, and then spend that money on AdWords advertising for your other sites.

If you're asking if there is a way to automatically transfer your AdSense earnings into your AdWords account the answer is **no**.

Comment: Pretty much this. It would make sense for Google to have some kind of credits system where this were possible though - 'credits' that they control would surely work out cheaper than having to payout then letting users spend that money on advertising again.

Comment: @Anonymous- to account for invalid clicks in AdSense, adjustments in AdWords, refunds, credits, debits wouldn't be impossible for Google. But quite a bit of integration between the two systems. Who knows how far apart they are considering Google acquired those companies a long time ago.